# python dateutil.parser wrong (??) parsing

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, python-dateutil

I am trying the following (python 3.6)

```
import dateutil.parser as dp
t1 = '0001-04-23T02:25:43.511Z'
t2 = '0001-04-23T01:25:43.511Z'
print(dp.parse(t1))
print(dp.parse(t2))
```

which gives me

```
0001-04-23 02:25:43.511000+00:00
0023-01-04 01:25:43.511000+00:00
```

In various similar cases, when the year string has form `00XY` and the hour string `XY`, the parser seems to produce the wrong output. Am I missing something, or is this a bug?

Comment: What happens if you use isoparse instead of parse?

Comment: `dateutil.parser.isoparse('0001-04-23T01:25:43.511Z')` gives `datetime.datetime(1, 4, 23, 1, 25, 43, 511000, tzinfo=tzutc())` - but so does simple parse. I can't reproduce this.

Comment: I can't seem to find `isoparse` method in parser

Comment: ok, it is in the 2.7 version of dateutil. works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [*was* a bug](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/293) in `dateutil` that was fixed (initial work [here](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/pull/130), but this specific edge case was fixed [here](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/pull/510)). Using `python-dateutil>=2.7.0` will fix your issue.

```
import dateutil
import dateutil.parser as dp

print(dateutil.__version__)
# 2.7.2

t1 = '0001-04-23T02:25:43.511Z'
t2 = '0001-04-23T01:25:43.511Z'

print(dp.parse(t1))
0001-04-23 02:25:43.511000+00:00

print(dp.parse(t2))
0001-04-23 01:25:43.511000+00:00
```

I do not recommend using [yearfirst](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50907945/467366) as it has other effects on how your datetime strings are parsed, and it is essentially an implementation detail that it works at all in the buggy case (since the bug involves interpreting `0001` as being equivalent to `01`, which it is not).

If you *do* know that you have an ISO-8601 formatted datetime, [`dateutil.parser.isoparse`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.isoparse) will be faster and stricter, and does not have this bug. It was also introduced in version 2.7.0:

```
print(isoparse('0001-04-23T02:25:43.511Z'))
# 0001-04-23 02:25:43.511000+00:00

print(isoparse('0001-04-23T01:25:43.511Z'))
# 0001-04-23 01:25:43.511000+00:00
```